# Pythonic method of determining if a list's contents change from odd to even values

Tags: list, python

Writing some test cases and my mind wanders, assuming there is a better way to write something like this.  I have a list, its numbers transition from all odd values to all even, doesn't matter where.  I need to assert this is the case, here's what I came up with:

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 2, 8, 6]

# find all the indexes of odd and even values
odds = [i for (i, v) in enumerate(values) if v % 2 == 1]
evens = [i for (i, v) in enumerate(values) if v % 2 == 0]

# indexes should be a continuous sequence: 0, 1, 2, 3 ... n
assert odds + evens == range(evens[-1] + 1)
```

Seems like a long way to go.  Suggestions on how this could be reduced?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, replaced with v % 2 == 0, ugly but self-contained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[x for x in values if x % 2 == 1] + [x for x in values if x % 2 == 0] == values
```

This is only true, if `values` starts with all of it's own odd values, followed by all of its even values.

Comment: This answer is very easy to understand, I'll give it that.  But it goes through the whole list twice, and concatenates the odd and even lists into yet another list, just to compare to the original.  I found dfan's and 6502's answers more elegant (and I would guess faster as well).  And dfan's answer has the additional advantage that it makes full use of the OP's original line of thinking, just short-circuits it to save time, memory, and verbosity.

Comment: @John - I totally agree. This is not fast. Elegant for me, is easy to understand and use. I my opinion, I do almost exactly what OP does. But, instead of concatenating indexes, I concatenated the items itself and so have to compare to the original list instead of range.

Comment: While not explicitly listed, performance is absolutely the least of my concerns.  As John said, it does follow my line of thinking, I can't claim a lack of bias! :)

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution is to consider that you allow only

```
odd->odd
odd->even
even->even
```

in other words the only forbidden transition is

```
even->odd
```

and this translates to

```
(0, 1) not in ((x%2, y%2) for x, y in zip(values, values[1:]))
```

Comment: You must *also* ensure that `odd->even` *has* happened.

Comment: That's not stated in the problem... as I understand it a sequence of all odd numbers or all even numbers is valid (it's also accepted by the original code).

Comment: The original code doesn't match the problem statement either then. "... its numbers transition from all odd values to all even ... I need to assert this is the case"

Comment: @Ignacio - IMHO a empty list is fine too, from all odd (nothing) to all even(nothing again). And besides, it **doesn't matter where**, so it doesn't have to be _in_ the list.

Comment: @ignacio: formally speaking an empty list is a list where all numbers are even (and funny enough they are also all odd). Logical negation of "all numbers are even" is "there is at least a number that is odd" and an empty list clearly doesn't satisfy this negation. There is nothing in the text that says an empty list shouldn't pass the test (an empty list is indeed made by an empty list of all odd numbers followed by an empty list of all even numbers).

Comment: Fair enough. But should an all-odd or all-even list pass?

Comment: @ignacio: as the problem is stated yes... a non-empty all-odd list can be seen as followed by an empty all-even list, and conversely a non-empty all-even list can be seen as preceded by an empty all-odd list. The original code indeed accepts all those side cases.

Comment: And that is true, all odd and all even is acceptable.  Since the transition can occur anywhere, that could be never.  Points for creativity. :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, you don't need to calculate `evens`:

```
assert odds == range(len(odds))
```

Comment: or even `assert odds[-1] == len(odds)-1` if you didn't want to compare the whole list.

Comment: I'll take an optimization, for sure. :)

Comment: The version in the comment doesn't handle the case of an empty list of odd indexes. Correct would be `assert not odds or odds[-1] == len(odds) - 1`.

Comment: @6502 Excellent point. Plus if we need to have both odds and evens in the original list, it should be `assert odds and odds[-1] == len(odds)-1 and odds[-1] != len(values)-1`.

Comment: it has been clarified by the question author that the list can be all-odd or all-even (including empty) and still being acceptable (see comments in my answer for a discussion on this topic).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the clarifications and solution from @6502, this generator approach uses `any()` to short circuit the iteration as soon as the test fails and only fails if an even to odd transition is detected.  The worst case performance is one full iteration if the test passes:

```
iter_val = iter(values)
assert not any(next(iter_val)%2 < v%2 for v in values[1:])
```

or

```
from itertools import izip
assert not any(i[0]%2 < i[1]%2 for i in izip(vals, vals[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(values[0] % 2) and (len(list(itertools.groupby(values, lambda x: x%2))) == 2)
```

Comment: This is hardly Pythonic; it reads more like a Perl one-liner contest submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
assert zip(*itertools.groupby(x%2 for x in values))[0] == (1, 0)
```

Or an easier to understand two-liner:

```
odds_and_evens = [x%2 for x in values]
assert odds_and_evens.index(0) == odds_and_evens.count(1)
```

If `values` is valid then `odds_and_evens` will be some number of `1` followed by only `0`, so it is valid if the first `0` comes after every `1`.

Both of these methods assume you need to have at least one odd followed by at least one even, which I don't think the OP has clarified.

If empty lists, all odd, or all even should be considered valid the following method works:

```
odds_and_evens = [x%2 for x in values]
assert odds_and_evens == sorted(odds_and_evens, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than collecting the indices, you can just calculate the transition point based on the assumption that all the odd values are at the start; and then check that there are no more odd values after that transition point.

Case where the assertion is true:

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 2, 8, 6]
odd_count = len([x for x in values if (x % 2)])
assert (not any(x for x in values[odd_count:] if (x % 2) != 0))
```

Case where the assertion is false:

```
values = [1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 44, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 2, 8, 6]
odd_count = len([x for x in values if (x % 2)])
assert (not any(x for x in values[odd_count:] if (x % 2) != 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Comment: I had thought about that strategy but never took it anywhere, that's pretty readable too.

Answer (score 1):

I think `filter` reads better than list comprehensions here, e.g.,

```
filter(isodd, values) + filter(iseven, values) == values
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to sort `values` by parity and see if anything changed:

```
assert sorted(values, key=lambda x: x % 2, reverse=True) == values
```

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat longer, but this would seem to capture all (even only, odd only, empty) in addition to requirements.  It only requires one modulo and one compare on the full list.  Not nearly as succinct (or clever) as Andrew's sorted answer, but faster(?) for long lists.

```
values= [1, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
evenOdd = [x%2 for x in values]

try:
    evenLoc=evenOdd.index(0)
    assert evenLoc != 0
except ValueError:
    evenLoc=len(evenOdd)

try:
    badActor=evenOdd[evenLoc:].index(1)
    assert False 
except ValueError:
    pass
```